# Simple JS program 3 item with negative and positive click boxes and total

Tags: javascript

Just started to learn javascript. I have a simple school project. I have 3 items with - and + buttons with total for each and then final total for all 3. I can't get the total button to not go below 0. It goes to negative values. The other 3 don't drop below 0 in their individual total count.

```
//set default values

let gb = 0 // Gingerbread
let cc = 0 // Chocolate Chip
let ss = 0 // Sugar Sprinkle
let total = 0

//set variables for quantity

var totalQuantity = document.getElementById('qty-total');
var gbQuantity = document.getElementById('qty-gb');
var ccQuantity = document.getElementById('qty-cc');
var ssQuantity = document.getElementById('qty-sugar');
//set event listener for Gingerbread cookie + button
document.getElementById("add-gb").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
{
    gb++
}
gbQuantity.textContent = gb;
total = total + 1;
totalQuantity.textContent = total;
console.log("Gingerbread + was clicked!")
})

// set even listener for Gingerbread cookie - button
document.getElementById("minus-gb").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
if(gb > 0)
{
     gb--
} 
   
gbQuantity.textContent = gb;

total = total - 1;
totalQuantity.textContent = total;
        
console.log("Gingerbread - was clicked!")
})

//set event listener for Chocolate chip cookie + button

document.getElementById("add-cc").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

{
    cc++
}

ccQuantity.textContent = cc;

total = total + 1;
totalQuantity.textContent = total;

console.log("Chocolate Chip + was clicked!")
})

//set event listener for Chocolate chip cookie - button

document.getElementById("minus-cc").addEventListener("click", function(e) 
{
if(cc > 0)
{
    cc--

}
    
ccQuantity.textContent = cc;
total = total - 1;
totalQuantity.textContent = total;

console.log("Chocolate Chip - was clicked!")
})

//set event listener for Sugar Sprinkle cookies + button

document.getElementById("add-sugar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

{
    ss++
}

ssQuantity.textContent = ss;
totalQuantity = document.getElementById("qty-total");
total = total + 1;
totalQuantity.textContent = total;

console.log("Sugar Sprinkle + was clicked!")
})

//set event listener for Sugar Sprinkle cookies - button

document.getElementById("minus-sugar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
if ( ss > 0)
{
    ss--
}    

ssQuantity.textContent = ss;

total = total - 1;

totalQuantity.textContent = total;

console.log("Sugar Sprinkle - was clicked!")
})
```

So the total quantity keeps dropping below 0 after the minus buttons are still clicked. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a codepen? https://codepen.io/

Comment: "*I have 3 items with - and + buttons with total for each and then final total for all 3.*" - and if you [edit] your question to include the ("*[mcve]*" HTML, CSS to go with your JavaScript) we may be able to properly help you. Please note, while you *can* post a demo to an external site you are *required* to post the relevant code here in your question; ideally as a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your code, one way to achieve this would be to wrap a condition around all parts of your code `total = total - 1;` which decrement total....

```
if(total >= 1){
  total = total - 1;
}
```

So now, total will only decrease if it is currently a value greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: I think I would use this approach as well but not around all parts of your code just the subtraction part. Because you don't want to run this code again and again when you are adding instead of subtracting items. So just put the above code inside the minus sugar code block

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the `total` variable with this at start of code. This will ensure that `total` starts with the correct sum.

`total = totalQuantity.textContent`

And it should be ensured that the `qty-total` in UI should be set to `qty-gb + qty-cc + qty-sugar`

---

Alternatively, you could also do this at the start:

`total = gbQuantity + ccQuantity + ssQuantity`

Answer (score 1):

There's at least two simple fixes to consider:

1. Just make sure that the if-check curly brackets in your substraction functions wrap around not only `cc--`, `gc--` and `ss--`, but also make sure that the logic that substracts from the total (i.e., these lines - `total = total - 1`) are also inside the same if-condition.
   Otherwise currently you're substracting from the total, no matter if you substracted from the `gc`, `ss` or `cc`

OR

2. Instead of doing calculations with the total like `total = total + 1` or `total = total - 1`, you could always just say that `total = gc + cc + ss`, for example. :)

Comment: Thanks. I misplaced the closing curly bracket, which didn't include the total = total -1 in the same if condtion.